# Movie Database - Load images from API or locally?

Tags: seo, google-search, images, api

We are creating a movie database site and I have a big dilemma...

Shall we keep the movie posters, episodes, screen images in our host or shall we use TMDB (themoviedb API) for loading those images? What is better in terms of SEO?

I'm thinking that saving those images locally will take a lot of disk space but Google will crawl those images and it will be better for SEO. Also I can optimize all those images and load the page faster since we are using a good dedicated server.

In the case of using TMDB API will affect the SEO? Is it good to load sources from external sites in terms of SEO even its API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to do it yourself.

1. You don't want to rely on an API (if it goes down or it gets discontinued).
2. More often than not, relying on external APIs will slow down the load times of your site. As you probably already know, page speed is a ranking factor.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to host images by yourself. It will be better, and you will be safe (your images always will be yours, but any DB can install hotlink protection).

Comment: Yeah, i agree with your thinking and most probably that i will do..